# scipy.special.expn(n,x) for complex values?

Tags: scipy

I want to evaluate numerically this integral

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html

which seems that is implemented in Python using Scipy. In particular with

https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.special.expn.html#scipy.special.expn

I want to evaluate this function for pure complex values (z = i*x, where x is Real), but seems that is not working. Do you know how can be solved?

```
from scipy import special
print special.expn(2, 1j)
```

I get:

"""ufunc 'expn' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''"""

Do you know how can be solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind the additional dependency, you can use the [`expint`](http://mpmath.org/doc/1.1.0/functions/expintegrals.html#mpmath.expint) function in [`mpmath`](http://mpmath.org/).  It handles complex arguments:

```
In [153]: import mpmath

In [154]: mpmath.mp.prec = 100

In [155]: mpmath.expint(2, 1j)
Out[155]: mpc(real='-0.084410950559573886889031770373614', imag='-0.50406706190692837198985611774113')
```

Comment: thank you very much! I didn't know the existence of the expint function

Comment: Realize that `mpmath.expint` uses arbitrary-precision arithmetic, and hence will be vastly slower than the double-precision SciPy versions in the cases where they overlap.   With `mpmath.mp.prec` set to double precision, i.e. 53, I find that it is about 100x slower than `scipy.expn` on my machine for real arguments.   (It's also not vectorized for NumPy arrays: you have to use `map`.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `exp1` instead of `expn` (see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.exp1.html#scipy.special.exp1)):

> Exponential integral E_1 of complex argument z

Sample:

```
import scipy.special as special
special.exp1(1+1j)
>>(0.0002816244519814326-0.17932453503935886j)
```

Comment: `exp1(z)` only works for `expn(1,z)`. How do you evaluate `expn(2, 1j)` with `exp1`?